# PHP decode acute

Tags: php, special-characters

I've got string:

```
$str = "Końc&oacute;wki";
```

My target string is:

```
$str = "Końcówki";

echo html_entity_decode($d); // Końc�wki

echo utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($d)); // KoÅcówki
```

How to decode it without crashing other special chars?

Comment: What is `$d` variable ?

Answer (score 2):

The character needs to be decoded into some charset. The string already contains a character which is encoded in a specialized charset. You need to tell `html_entities_decode` to decode to that same charset. At the moment there's a mismatch between the two.

```
html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'your charset here')
```

Comment: echo html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); worked, thanks